# How can I get camera details through Unity and C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

I am trying to use the WebCamTexture property in Unity - Windows, Unity Version 5.2 at the time I am writing this. I can use WebCamTexture.height and WebCamTexture.requestedHeight.

But how do I find out what the user's camera is capable of? What if the user has a camera that isn't HD capable and I want to get a picture that's 1280x720? I'd love to hear your input for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the resolution you want to have. If it's not supported by the hardware it will use the closest supported value.

> The requested width, height and framerate specified by the parameters may not be supported by the chosen camera. In such cases, the closest available values will be used.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-ctor.html